# Set Scroll bar position of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

So I have a vanilla DataGridView in a WinForms solution.

As you tab through the cells in the DataGrid eventually you reach a point where the selected cell is only half in view. In order to view it you must scroll over.

Well this is obviously something that I want to handle automatically so the question is....

How do I enable my DataGridView to scroll automatically as the user tabs.

I searched for a scroll bar index value or position value but couldn't seem to find anything.

DataGrid 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx

Comment: I **can't** reproduce what you said. In fact the `DataGridView` **does** what you need by default, when I tab between cells, the selected cell will be automatically brought into view with the whole cell displayed.

Comment: @KingKing Just because you can't reproduce it doesn't mean it's not a real problem. I'm not imagining it.

Comment: @KingKing for the record the below answer solved the problem, so I guess if it has a soluition, it inherinetly must have a problem.

Comment: You just need to create an empty project, add a datagridview with some columns and rows then you will see **why your problem is so strange**. The `DataGridView` designers were not such stupid. The selected cell won't be displayed in one piece only when the cell width exceed the DataGridView's Width.

Comment: BTW, the solution below **can't** solve your problem generally. Suppose your `partially displayed column` has some `unpredicted` Width, you can't base on the `FirstDisplayedCell`. It can show your cell you want **at first place** but can't place your cell at the right position so that **it is enough to display your cell in once piece** like the default behavior.

Comment: @KingKing well it did solve the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like `FirstDisplayedCell` to control your scroll.

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0];
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx

Comment: SImple. Works well. Thank you.